# selectize.js include option separators

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I have a select list of countries, where I'm using options with just dashes as separators. Like so...

```
<select class="form-control" id="Country" name="Country">
    <option disabled="disabled">-------------------</option>
    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
    <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="IN">India</option>
    <option value="US">United States Of America</option>
    <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
    <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
    <option disabled="disabled">-------------------</option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
    ...
```

However when I "selectize" this, these separator options disappear.

I don't need labelled option groups, I just want a way to visually separate items in the list. Is there a recommended way to do this with selectizejs?

Answer (score 0):

The reason they are not showing up is because they don't have a value. Try giving them a null value and you should be able to see it.

```
<select class="form-control" id="Country" name="Country">
    <option value="XX" disabled="disabled">-------------------</option>
    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
    <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="IN">India</option>
    <option value="US">United States Of America</option>
    <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
    <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
    <option value="XX" disabled="disabled">-------------------</option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
    ...
```